# How can I find out a file's MIME type (Content-Type)?

Tags: linux, bash, content-type, mime, mime-types

Is there a way to find out the MIME type (or is it called "Content-Type"?) of a file in a Linux bash script?

The reason I need it is because ImageShack appears to need it to upload a file, as for some reason it detects the .png file as an `application/octet-stream` file.

I’ve checked the file, and it really is a PNG image:

```
$ cat /1.png 
?PNG
(with a heap load of random characters)
```

This gives me the error:

```html
$ curl -F "fileupload=@/1.png" http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php
<links>
<error id="wrong_file_type">Wrong file type detected for file 1.png:application/octet-stream</error>
</links>
```

This works, but I need to specify a MIME-TYPE.

```
$ curl -F "fileupload=@/1.png;type=image/png" http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

Use `file`. Examples:

```
> file --mime-type image.png
image.png: image/png

> file -b --mime-type image.png
image/png

> file -i FILE_NAME
image.png: image/png; charset=binary
```

Comment: Not if you use the Git bash under windows.

Comment: To get **just** the mime-type you could do: `file --mime-type FILE_NAME | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @JustinJenkins -b omits the filename so `file -b --mime-type FILE_NAME` returns just the mime type

Comment: or `kmimetypefinder filename`

Comment: Doesn't recognize `application/xml` or `text/xml`

Comment: and `file -bi FILE_NAME` returns "mime-type" and "charset" only.

Comment: Also wrong for XML: `file -b --mime-type image.svg` returns `image/svg` where it should be `image/svg+xml`

Answer (score 38):

one of the other tool (besides file) you can use is `xdg-mime`

eg `xdg-mime query filetype <file>`

if you have yum,

`yum install xdg-utils.noarch`

An example comparison of xdg-mime and file on a Subrip(subtitles) file

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype subtitles.srt
application/x-subrip

$ file --mime-type subtitles.srt
subtitles.srt: text/plain
```

in the above file only show it as plain text.

Comment: xdg-mime query filetype install.sql;    xprop:  unable to open display ''

Comment: xdg-mime is a bash script an relies heavily on environment variables. Some of them e.g. DE are not set if you are not logged into a session. Check it out yourself `$ less $(which xdg-mime)`

Answer (score 12):

**file version < 5 :** file -i -b /path/to/file
**file version >=5 :** file --mime-type -b /path/to/file

Comment: what do you mean by file version?

Comment: @user2867106 I think he mean the version of the file command.

Answer (score 7):

Try the [`file`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm) command with `-i` option.

`-i` option Causes the file command to output mime type strings rather than the more traditional human readable ones. Thus it may say `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` rather than `ASCII text`.

Answer (score 2):

file --mime works, but not --mime-type. at least for my RHEL 5.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting MIME-types, use the aptly named "[mimetype](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mimetype)" command.

It has a number of options for formatting the output, it even has an option for backward compatibility to "file".

But most of all, it accepts input not only as file, but also via stdin/pipe, so you can avoid temporary files when processing streams.