# Unable to load shared library 'urlmon.dll' on linux environment

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, centos

ASP .NET Core 3.1

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'urlmon.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liburlmon.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at FindMimeFromData(IntPtr pBC, String pwzUrl, Byte[] pBuffer, Int32 cbSize, String pwzMimeProposed, Int32 dwMimeFlags, IntPtr& ppwzMimeOut, Int32 dwReserved)
at ValidateMimeType(List`1 colBytesFile, htconstructorparams htConstructorParams) in \Share.cs:line 5048
at ValidateFileMimeType(HttpRequest request, htconstructorparams htConstructorParams) in \Share.cs:line 5019
at FileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in ''\FileMiddleware.cs:line 43
at JwtMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IUserSessionService _userSessionService) in ''\JwtMiddleware.cs:line 79
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at ErrorHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, hk_log_dbcontext logDbContext)

Answer (score 0):

`urlmon.dll` is a Windows component.

ASP.NET Core is cross-platform, but when you run it on Linux, you can't access any libraries, features or files that are Windows specific, such as `urlmon.dll`.

If you want to find out the mime type of a file on Linux, you might have to use a Linux-specific solution such as [How can I find out a file's MIME type (Content-Type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227182/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-mime-type-content-type).